# Debug Delphi multi-thread app - how to get the one consuming 100% CPU

Tags: multithreading, delphi, debugging

I'm debugging a multi-thread delphi app.
We are having a trouble that, after connect to the server, the client app is getting 100% of the CPU.
Is there a way for me to debug and know shich thread is dois that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) will give you usage details down to the thread level for any process.

1. Run your app
2. Run Process Explorer (after downloading it ;-)
3. Double click on your executable in the process list
4. Select the Threads tab and there you will see:

   1. The Thread ID
   2. CPU Usage
   3. Cycles Delta
   4. And the start address

The TID ought to be enough to nail down your CPU hogging thread.

Comment: +1 for beating me.  To get the process details, double click on the process and select the "Threads" tab.  It will take a moment to refresh.

Comment: The app helped me, thanks. Turns out a call to a method, that was working properly with Indy 9 - but once we changed to Indy 10 - problems on a specific thread calling a indy method.

Answer (score 3):

As Paul Sasik suggests, [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) is probably what you want to do.  If your debugging strategy involves monitoring code that is in your application itself, use [`GetThreadTimes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683237(VS.85).aspx).